# Which PayPal API Permission?

Tags: api, paypal, payment-services

I am building an app that will continually check for a condition... and when that condition is met, it will do something and then charge my users $30 for doing it. So I need two things:

1. I need my users to authorize me to charge their accounts.
2. I need to know how to charge them once I perform my service.

I think that once I know which permission to request (I already have the code to request the permission and store the access token), I will be able to figure out how to request the payments. So I really only need an answer to #1.

Answer (score 1):

Look at RECURRING_PAYMENTS. I'm not 100% clear on what you are trying to do, but this sounds like the thing you need.